# history.go (-1) not working in internet explorer

Tags: php, javascript, html

When I use the history.go(-1) command as follows it works fine, but takes very long to reaload the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     javascript:history.go(-1);
</script>
```

But when I try and use it in my php code, it just gives me an error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Here is my code

```
<?php header(sprintf("Location: %s", "javascript:window.history.go(-1);")); ?>
```

In ff and chrome this works really well, it quickly returns to previous page, without reloading. Not so in ie.

Comment: That works in Chrome and Firefox??  That's scary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739443/javascript-history-go-1-not-working-in-internet-explorer-7

Comment: You're putting this in your location header? Why? Also, which version of IE are you referring to?

Comment: Just don't do this. The header is for HTTP, not for JS!

Comment: ie 9. This is the only method i could find that returns to the previous page quickly without reloading. What im trying to do is this. When the user is on page A he will click on a button, which redirect the browser to page B, which runs a php script, and then promptly returns to page A without the user seeing that he has been redirected to page B.

Comment: Thank you. Didnt know about AJAX until now, but it seem like the route I should be taking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common way to go back to the previous page is not to pass JavaScript into your header, but instead to direct the user to the referer of the current page:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

Since you said you're using IE9, you should know that [IE9 doesn't support the HTML5 History API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history). Moving forward you can rest assured that [IE10 does support this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but for IE9 you won't be able to use these methods without using something like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

If you simply want to load a page asynchronously, you can use an [XHR object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or a tool like jQuery which greatly simplifies the otherwise verbose code. With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can load a page as trivially as:

```
$("#container").load("targetPage.php #container");
```

Which would load the contents of `#container` from `targetPage.php` into your `#container` element on the current page.

Comment: _Note:_ always use `exit;` after `header('location:'.$url);` and you should use `header` function before you send content to browser. otherwise it will produce `E_Warning` "headers already sent".

Comment: Upvoted, @PLB. Very important things that are too often forgotten.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but it reloads the previous page. What I want is that it returns to the exact state and position of the previous page, without reloading it.

Comment: @user1900937 IE9 doesn't support the History APIs.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
history.back(1);
```